# Swift returning fatal error after pressing button and getting its currentTitle

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So, I am following a video class of Switf for iOS 8 on iTunes (https://itunes.com/StanfordSwift if anyone is interested, its free), and well, now of course iOS 9 available and I think I am having a problem for the different versions and I cannot find ANYTHING on the web about this. I hope that anyone reading this can help me out a bit.

The project is about a Calculator, so I have in the UI the buttons with the numbers, these buttons sends its value (currentTitle) to my appendDigit function. Xcode does not mark any error, but still, at runtime when I press the button I get a fatal error, and honestly, I don't understand what is going on.

I tried setting and IF statement for when its available currentTitle or not, but well, this doesn't help at all since I need to be getting the buttons number.

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {

    let digit = sender.currentTitle!

    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
        display.text = display.text! + digit
    }else{
        display.text = digit
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
    }

}
```

The line that is causing the error is: `let digit = sender.currentTitle!`

Here is also a screenshot of what I am getting, seems that the button is sending the value empty... but as you can see, there are the numbers!

[image]

Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *numbers* on the buttons, you claimed. But I think some of them, or one of them, don't.

The crash is caused by unwrapping an Optional value, which is the following line:

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle!
```

By looking at your layout in storyboard, I think you are connecting a lot of buttons to the same `IBAction` method, which is perfectly fine.

But as mentioned, some of them or one of them, whose `currentTitle` have not been set either programmatically or in storyboard ("title"), hence the crash.

So, please double check whether one of them or some of them whose `currentTitle` have not been set.

I was able to re-produce the error by deliberately leaving out `currentTitle` in one of the buttons. The crash occurred exactly like the one you're experiencing:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Or, one could proceed in a safer way:

```
@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton)
{
    if let digit = sender.currentTitle
    {
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber
        {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        }
        else
        {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I call being helpful! I was in Germany for 7 months in Frankfurt and never met such a smart girl (sorry for the flirting, can't help it). I am a newbie in iOS and, of course, to swift! But, really, thank you very much. I found that the title types were "attributes" instead of "plain" and that was what it was causing it. :)

Comment: @Unheiling Bitte, kann ich einen gewissen Kontakt mit Ihnen? :D